# How to export formatted XML output by using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I try to do formatted XML output using SQL Server 2016.

This is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM [GRADUATE]
FOR XML PATH('applicant'), ROOT('applicantsuniversity'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

The output is

[image]

The output I have to submit needs to look like this:

[image]

Question #1: how can I put this line to show in my code?

[image]

Question #2: how to treat null values?

How can I adapt my code to show an output like this:

[image]

not like this:

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need put the whole thing in a subquery and create the root element manually.

Use the `, TYPE` option to embed XML within other XML queries. The subquery should not have a column name, or you will get a second level of nesting.

Use `@` in the column name to specify an attribute.

Remove the `, ELEMENTS XSINIL` to get rid of `xsi:nil` attributes. If you actually want to show empty elemnts then you can do `ISNULL(maidenName, '')`

```sql
SELECT
  [@university] = '123456',
  (
    SELECT g.*
    FROM GRADUATE g
    FOR XML PATH('applicant'), TYPE
  )
FOR XML PATH('applicants');
```

If you actually need to get that `university` attribute from the data then you need some kind of aggregation. `STRING_AGG` would make sense if you have it in your version, but you do need to cast it back to XML afterwards.

```
SELECT
  [@university] = g.university,
  CAST(g.xmlData AS xml)
FROM (
    SELECT
      g.university,
      xmlData = STRING_AGG(x.xmlData, '')
    FROM GRADUATE g
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT g.*
        FOR XML PATH('applicant')
    ) x(xmlData)
) g
FOR XML PATH('applicants');
```